# Multiple asp:fileUpload file instances (added separately)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, file, upload

I have an application that uses asp.net C# and I need to create a page where I can upload files in different times.

The idea:
Step 1: Click on "add files" button, select one or more files, press ok.
Step 2: Click again on "add files" button, select one or more files, press ok.
Step 3: Click on "finish" to send the files and textfields.

The problem:
When I add a file or more a single time (step 1) they get posted to the back-end and I can save them normally. However when I do step 1 and step 2, the form overwrites the previsouly added files list. Is not that it saves the files deleting the others, this is pre-back-end.

I've checked a lot of tutorials but all I could find are showing how to upload multiple files (just an attribute of asp:FileUpload). Everytime I try to add files from different folders or in different times, they always send only the last ones I added.

Can anyone help me out?
Thank you.

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I got it done by converting each file into a base64 string. Probably not the best solution but it worked. Thanks

Comment: Store the files in a temp folder and display them. Then when the user is finished process those files and clear the temp data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it but it worked for me:

1- I created an "onChange" javascript event on the asp:FileUpload control.

2- For each file inside the fileupload.files I converted them to a Base64 string and passed them with their file names to a C# webmethod.

3- Inside the webmethod I stored the string and file names.

4- After clicking on "finish", other C# method is called to loop through the temporary files list and save them all.

Thanks